# How can a systemd user service run the xclip command?

Tags: systemd, watch

I'd like to automatically clear the clipboard a few seconds after use.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

LOCKFILE=/tmp/.clearclip-lock
if [ -e ${LOCKFILE} ] && kill -0 `cat ${LOCKFILE}`; then
  exit 1
fi
trap "rm -f ${LOCKFILE}; exit" INT TERM EXIT
touch ${LOCKFILE}
echo $$ > ${LOCKFILE}

if xclip -o -selection clipboard 1>&2 2>/dev/null; then
  if watch -n 0.5 -t --chgexit xclip -o -selection clipboard @>/dev/null; then
    sleep 10
    xsel -bc
  fi
fi

rm -f ${LOCKFILE}
```

I've only just started playing around with this crude executable file called `~/mypath/clearclip` which I'd like to trigger with a user local systemd timer. Anyway, the service throws an error `Error opening terminal: unknown.`

```
# ~/.local/share/systemd/user/clearclip.service
[Unit]
Description=clear the clipboard
ConditionFileIsExecutable=%h/_path/clearclip.sh

[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=%h/_path/clearclip.sh
Type=oneshot
```

My main question is:

Is there a tool to perform the same-but-non-interactive functionality of `watch -g`? What's your approach? Would you write the output to tmp files in a while loop to compare them, revert to expect, or something else?

Another question is: How would a dual-timer setup look like?

e.g. timer would check when the clipboard changes and trigger (or restart) another timer which clears the clipboard selection

**Edit 25/07/2018:**

I've given up on using this script with a user timer this week. I was playing around with zpty to emulate a terminal to get rid of the `opening terminal` error but I ended up just putting a `clearclip &` in `~/.config/zsh/.zlogin`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
# zmodload zsh/zpty

oclip=""
let count='-1'
let timeout=70

clipchanged() {
  if ! xclip -o -selection clipboard 2>/dev/null 1>&2; then
    count='-1'
    return 1
  fi
  clip="$(xclip -o -selection clipboard)"
  if [[ -z "$clip" ]] || [[ "$oclip" == "$clip" ]]; then
    return 1
  elif [[ -z "$oclip" ]]; then
    oclip="$clip"
    return 1
  else
    (( count=timeout ))
    oclip="$clip"
    return 0
  fi
}

while true; do
  if (( count > 0 )); then
    ((count--))
    # echo -n "\r\033[K$count"
  fi
  if (( count == 0 )); then
    xsel -bc
  fi
  if clipchanged; then
    (( count=timeout ))
  fi
  sleep .5
done
```

**Edit 9/07/2020:**

I added an appropriate question in the title, even though I quickly abandoned the idea. To clear the clipboard or act on changes I'm using the `--watch` option from `wl-copy(1)`:

```
--watch command...
    Instead of pasting once and exiting, continuously watch the clipboard for changes, and run the specified command each time a new selection appears. The spawned process can read the clipboard contents from its standard input. This mode requires a compositor that supports the wlroots data-control protocol.
```

Comment: Is this only about the X clipboard? Why use systemd? Can the service even run the `xclip` command? You'd need to at least export the DISPLAY, XAUTHORITY etc variables. I've never played with this, but I guess you'd need a similar approach to what is needed for cron. Have a look at [Using notify-send with cron](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/111188)

Comment: Note that in principle you could run a dozen X servers on your computer, with users using them remotely etc. You need some way to associate this "service" to a single user with a single X server in a single session, so the appropriate place to start this would be during X login, not in systemd. And yes, the X server sends events when the selection changes, but I don't know any ready-made commandline tools that can hook into that.

Comment: Thank you both for your making the problem clear, I was quite naive. I have a single user running wayland on Arch linux, only two programs require Xwayland, and I never use the graphical session remotely. The point is not to store information on the X clipboard indefinitely. Indeed, I thought I'd like a systemd user unit so that I may at some point bind the unit to additional sessions run by different users. But it may be better to start a process to directly hook into an event.

Comment: I tried to include the environment as suggested in the liked answer, but I think either xclip, watch or xsel expect a terminal to connect to. I've had no luck setting `StandardInput=` and `StandardOutput=`.